# Check if char is in () block

Tags: java, regex

I would like to check if a semicolon (`;`) is in the brackets of an `AND` or `OR` block within a string.

For example:

```
IF(AND(ROUND($GX18-SUM(0)/$M$12;2)<=0;$AK$7=1);0;OR(1;A2)+O2)
```

If it's **not** within an `AND` or `OR` then I replace it with `#`:

```
IF(AND(ROUND($GX18-SUM(0)/$M$12;2)<=0$AK$7=1)#0#OR(1;A2)+O2)
```

I know how to do the substitution, but how do I detect whether the `;` is inside such a block?

**UPDATE**

Using regex possibly seems quite complex. However, to break down the problem:

How to detect if a certain char(`;`) is within an `AND(...)` or `OR(...)`? This would help me a lot!

Comment: You can't use a regex to handle arbitrary nesting, as you would need here for the parentheses in your boolean expression.

Comment: Regex is not powerful enough for this.

Comment: @ScottHunter Its basically an excel formula, which I would like to parse. So how can I detect the parentheses and the "outside" `;`. I am greatful for your suggestions!

Comment: @Kare as discussed with your previous question, this is actually very difficult if possible at all with regex, or at least with regex only. I suggest you implement your own parser and recurse different nested levels of parenthesis / alongside a parent-children node relationship. It might be a lot of work depending on the variety of your cases.

Comment: Regular expressions are an application of context-free grammars. Hence, you need more powerful languages to express your needs, more specifically a context sensitive language. I agree with @Mena - you need to implement your own parser.

Comment: @Mena Thx for your answer! I broke my problem down to 2 cases. My problem is to detect if the `;` is in AND/OR brackets or not.(Just these two cases.) If I know that the `;` is in one block I can mark it with another char like `!`. However, how to detect it?

Comment: @Kare you're welcome. The issue is precisely how to detect the context (borrowing from rlinden's expression). The replacement is the most trivial part once you're context aware, but for that regex will hardly help you.

Comment: @Mena Thx for your reply! I think to detect context, I am a bit to a newbie right now. Any recommendations for that?

Comment: @Kare that's the part when you want to implement your own parser. It'll be easy to google out some literature about it, but the implementation might be quite complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope following java code helps to resolve your problem,

```
String str = "IF(AND(ROUND($GX18-SUM(0)/$M$12;2)<=0$AK$7=1);0;OR(1;A2)+O2)";
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        int count = 0;
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            temp = temp + ch[i];
            if ("AND(".equals(temp) || "OR(".equals(temp)) {
                count++;
            }
            if ("(".equals(temp) && count > 0) {
                count++;
            }
            if (")".equals(temp) && count > 0) {
                count--;
            }
            if (";".equals(temp) && count == 0) {
                ch[i] = '#';
            }
            if ((!"AND(".startsWith(temp) && !"OR(".startsWith(temp)) || temp.length() > 4) {
                temp = "";
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Expected Data >> " + String.valueOf(ch));
```

Comment: Why are you doing temp.length > 4?

Comment: temp value keep on append to the next character if it starts with "AND(" or "OR(". So to avoid that we are checking that "length_value > 4" & make the temp variable as "". Ex: Now temp value is "AND(R" then we need to reset the value as "".